# Using Jpa inside apache felix framework implementation

Tags: jpa, osgi, eclipselink, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I was trying to implement an OSGi application , application has servlet(implemented using jetty), jaxb(using eclipselink moxy), and Jpa part(the problem part). I was trying to use eclipselink inside apache felix container for jpa functionality, I tried various approach but couldn't implement it. I just need some working example or tutorial link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to use jpa in felix is to use Apache Karaf as it has pre packaged features for eclipselink as well as Aries JPA which makes it easier to use any jpa provider in OSGi.

See [example with declarative services](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist-ds), or [with blueprint.](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist-blueprint-cdi)

For plain felix I recommend to use bndtools to get the list of bundles and also to be able to directly run felix.

[I started a tutorial to package and run the tasklist-ds example using bndtools](https://github.com/cschneider/bndtools-tutorials)

Comment: Hey Christian, thanks for replying, my osgi application is intended to run on felix(as i require only core osgi framework), could you suggest some resources which i  can refer for jpa in felix , as all the broad requirement has been met, only jpa problem is needed to cracked?

Comment: It is not easy to get jpa running on plain felix as several different bundles and configs are needed. I at least recommend that you use bndtools to let the resolver find the needed set of bundles.